# Stream multiple RTPS cameras in the same window using Java

Tags: java, video-streaming, rtsp, javacv

I made a project to stream 4 cameras with RTSP protocol using the javacv library, but when I use CanvasFrame to display the stream, it is done in a new window.
I would like to know if I can make the 6 cameras stay in the same window using this library.
Or if anyone knows of a library where I can do this, I would like to know which one, so I can research about it.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String testPath1 = "url1";
    String testPath2 = "url2";

    FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(testPath1);
    FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber1 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(testPath2);
    FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber2 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(testPath1);
    FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber3 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(testPath2);

    Frame frame;
    Frame frame1;
    Frame frame2;
    Frame frame3;

    CanvasFrame canvasFrame;
    CanvasFrame canvasFrame1;
    CanvasFrame canvasFrame2;
    CanvasFrame canvasFrame3;
    CanvasFrame canvasFrame4;
//    CanvasFrame canvasFrame7;
    CanvasFrame[] canvasFrames;

    public Test() throws IOException, CanvasFrame.Exception {
//        frameGrabber.setOption("", "");
//        frameGrabber1.setOption("", "");
//        frameGrabber2.setOption("", "");
//        frameGrabber3.setOption("", "");

        frameGrabber.start();
        frameGrabber1.start();
        frameGrabber2.start();
        frameGrabber3.start();

        frame = frameGrabber.grab();
        frame1 = frameGrabber1.grab();
        frame2 = frameGrabber2.grab();
        frame3 = frameGrabber3.grab();

        canvasFrame1 = new CanvasFrame("Canvas1");
        canvasFrame2 = new CanvasFrame("Canvas2");
        canvasFrame3 = new CanvasFrame("Canvas3");
        canvasFrame4 = new CanvasFrame("Canvas4");
//        canvasFrame7 = new CanvasFrame("Button");

//        JButton jButton1 = new JButton("My Button");
//        canvasFrame7.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0, gap 10", "grow", "grow"));
//        canvasFrame7.add(jButton1, "w 100:100:100, h 40:40:40");
        canvasFrames = new CanvasFrame[]{canvasFrame1, canvasFrame2, canvasFrame3, canvasFrame4};
    }

    public void showWindow() throws FFmpegFrameGrabber.Exception {
        while (canvasFrame1.isVisible()) {
            frame = frameGrabber.grab()
            frame1 = frameGrabber1.grab()
            frame2 = frameGrabber2.grab()
            frame3 = frameGrabber3.grab()

            canvasFrame1.showImage(frame);
            canvasFrame2.showImage(frame1);
            canvasFrame3.showImage(frame2);
            canvasFrame4.showImage(frame3);

            canvasFrame.tile(canvasFrames);
        }

        frameGrabber.stop();
        canvasFrame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CanvasFrame.Exception {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.showWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the short answer is "no".  The long answer is, "it's complicated".  With a bit of effort, it should be possible to extract the `Canvas` workflow from the `CanvasFrame`, which would allow you to add multiple instances of the custom `Canvas` to your container

Comment: We can use a FrameConverter to convert Frame objects to BufferedImage, Android Bitmap, JavaFX Image, etc, and then display those however we need: http://bytedeco.org/news/2015/04/04/javacv-frame-converters/